# Update Statement with where clause in java:Netbeans

Tags: java, sql-update, where-clause, netbeans-8

This was written to update the table with the new data but on executing the following code it showing a null pointer exception at *prepare statement*. Can anyone just help in finding where i went wrong!

```
String a= jTextField1.getText();
String b= jTextField2.getText();
String c= jTextField3.getText();
String d= jTextField4.getText();
String e= jTextField5.getText();
String f= jTextField6.getText();
String g= jTextField7.getText();
String i= jTextField8.getText();

try {
String s2="update loginsys set 
appointtype='"+a+"',appointname='"+b+"',appointh='"+c+"',
appointm='"+d+"',appointd='"+e+"',appointmo='"+f+"',appointy='"+g+"'where 
username='"+f+"';";

    PST=conn.prepareStatement(s2);
    PST.setString(1,a);
    PST.setString(2,b);
    PST.setString(3,c);
    PST.setString(4,d);
    PST.setString(5,e);
    PST.setString(6,f); 
    PST.setString(7,g);
    PST.setString(8,f);

RS=PST.executeQuery();
if(RS.next()){         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Appointment was fixed");
    appointments.this.setVisible(false);
    new list().setVisible(true);}
   else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Appointment was not fixed");
```

Comment: First, go back and read the tutorial on [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Then update your query string to be more like `update loginsys set appointtype=?,appointname=?,appointh=?,appointm=?,appointd=?,appointmo=?,appointy=? where username=?`

Comment: and then call `executeUpdate`

Comment: for all we know, conn is null. provide all relevant code, and stop thinking netbeans has any impact on any of this.

Comment: First, have to load driver and create connection.

Answer (score 0):

First, go back and read the tutorial on [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Second, update your query string to be more like `update loginsys set appointtype=?,appointname=?,appointh=?,appointm=?,appointd=?,appointmo=?,appointy=? where username=?`

Third use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery` - it will return the number of rows which were updated by the query

Comment: But is this causing the NPE?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Without more context, I suspect that the NPE is coming from `conn`